# Alchemy API / Bluemix not providing consistent results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I am using the [Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/) (Bluemix) and [rails wrapper](https://github.com/technekes/alchemy-api-rb) and am getting back nil for blocks of text. For example, consider below text:

"The Vancouver International Flamenco Festival presents renowned flamenco dancer Mercedes “La Winy” Amaya in an electrifying tribute to flamenco’s vibrant past, featuring the authentic Spanish Gypsy style of flamenco, from sumptuous sway to fierce flourish."

When I call the keyword endpoint, I only get keyword results about half the time. When I search the same block of text multiple times, I get results half the time and nil half the time.

I'm only making calls about once per second so rate capping is not an issue.

What is causing this to happen? Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 1):

Since AlchemyAPI was acquired and integrated into IBM Watson (as accessed via Bluemix), I don't think this question can be answered in it's current form. The AlchemyAPI services as used with the old Ruby wrapper mentioned above have been deprecated.

Instead, I suggest getting new credentials on the services for whichever aspect of AlchemyAPI you were using. The new products are mapped as follows:

AlchemyLanguage -> Watson Natural Language Understanding

AlchemyDataNews -> Watson Discovery

AlchemyVision -> Watson Visual Recognition